# why does nodejs add quotes to the objects? Unable to get correct result on mongodb find because of that

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the below `js` code where I am trying to take user input and based on that making a find request on `MongoDB`. Executing it in `Node console`.

```
var args = process.argv[2];
var params = {};
var myVar = 'ingredients';

var myquery = '/' + args + '/';
params[myVar] = myquery;
console.log(params);
```

I am using the `params` in the below chunk of code to find in the database which works fine when I give static string like:

```
dbo.collection("myDB").find({ingredients:/pak choi/})
```

but this gives an empty array as output.

```
dbo.collection("myDB").find(params).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
```

**console**:

```
node mongotry.js "pak choi"

{ ingredients: '/pak choi/' }
[]
```

The find fails because of the single quotes after ingredients:. How do I avoid those single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are not the issue. You are not using `.find()`correctly. The `.find()` takes a call back and returns the first element that satisfies the condition

```
myArray.find(element => element.ingredients === "/pak choi/")
```

If you are looking for all items that have `/pak choi/` you can use `.filter()`

```
myArray.filter(element => element.ingredients === "/pak choi/")
```

Comment: The find query works perfectly fine when I pass a hard coded string. The issue is that it does not when I pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

changing the below line of code got this working:

```
var myquery = '/' + args + '/';
```

to

```
var myquery = new RegExp(args);
```